# Set a value when the xml node contains a value

Tags: xslt

The code is passing out empty nodes for the various nodes I want to hardcode with specific text value in my output.

> This is my xml below

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="TRY%20v1.xsd">
    <row>
        <Invalid_Amount>155.2</Invalid_Amount>
        <Valid_Amount></Valid_Amount>
        <Trustee_Name>Bruce Wayne</Beneficiary_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Invalid_Amount></Invalid_Amount>
        <Valid_Amount>9880</Valid_Amount>
        <Trustee_Name>Clark Kent</Trustee_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Invalid_Amount>1665.2</Invalid_Amount>
        <Valid_Amount></Valid_Amount>
        <Trustee_Name>Diana Prince</Trustee_Name>
    </row>
</root>
```

> This is my current output

```
<Codac>
<Payment>
<Name>Bruce Wayne</Name>
<Expression><Expression/>
</Payment>
<Payment>
<Name>Clark Kent</Name>
<Expression><Expression/>
</Payment>
<Payment>
<Name>Diana Prince</Name>
<Expression><Expression/>
</Payment>
</Codac>
```

> this is my desired output that when the node  it should return the word THANKS but when the node <Valid_Amount> contains data, it should return WELCOME.

```
<Codac>
<Payment>
<Name>Bruce Wayne</Name>
<Expression>THANKS<Expression/>
</Payment>
<Payment>
<Name>Clark Kent</Name>
<Expression>WELCOME<Expression/>
</Payment>
<Payment>
<Name>Diana Prince</Name>
<Expression>THANKS<Expression/>
</Payment>
</Codac>
```

> This is my current xslt code

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Codac>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/row">
                <Payment>
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Trustee_Name"/>
                    </Name>
                    <Expression>
                   <xsl:call-template name="NotEmpty">
                     </xsl:call-template>
                </Expression>
                </Payment>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Codac>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="NotEmpty">
        <xsl:param name="S" select="Invalid_Amount != ''"/>
        <xsl:param name="T" select="Valid_Amount != ''"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="../row">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="Invalid_Amount =''">
           <xsl:value-of select="THANKS"/>
          </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="WELCOME"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Codac>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <Payment>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Trustee_Name"/>
                </Name>
                <Expression>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="Valid_Amount/text()">WELCOME</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>THANKS</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Expression>
            </Payment>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Codac>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello Michael thank you so much for you reply. The code seems to be returning only THANKS now. Do I quote both text?

Comment: That is not what I see. Here is a working example (using your XML input after correcting `/Beneficiary_Name>` to `</Trustee_Name>`!!): https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94humqP.